# CSS border-radius direction

Tags: css

I have a request to make these menu items:

Top menu:
[image]

Side menu:
[image]

I started with a `border-radius`, but I don't know how to make the other side to be 'outer radiuses', I believe both the top and bottom menu are mainly the same idea, I'll just have to play with the sizes and directions.

I'll soon share a jsFiddle of a version I'm working on, currently I haven't manage to do anything at all.

Comment: Something like this? http://csstube.ajmlab.com/tutorials/css-snippets/making-outer-border-radius-css ? or http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-radius-tabs.html ?

Comment: @sachleen man that's a 1:1 answer. Please post as answer and I'll mark it when available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you want to use the `:before` and `:after` selectors to create a little box with a border radius in the corners you want.

There are many examples online, here are a few:

- [Making Outer Border Radius Using CSS and CSS3](http://csstube.ajmlab.com/tutorials/css-snippets/making-outer-border-radius-css)
- [CSS3 - Tabs with inner and outer radii - no graphics](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-radius-tabs.html) - (free for personal use - not commercial)
- [Flared Borders with CSS](http://orderedlist.com/blog/articles/flared-borders-with-css/)